# cant download python on linux

Tags: python, linux

then was hinted to type: `apt --fix-broken install`
i typed sudo apt install python 3, it tells me python 3 is already the newest version and that i might want to run apt --fix-broken install to correct these but when i type that it returns:E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied) and then asks the same question ;Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

trying to download python 3.10.5 on linux chromebook have tried several ways so far but my linux terminal is keep returning this: `Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?`

please give a solution how to download python on chromeboox

Comment: It asks you `are you root?`. So check if you are root. If not, be root.

Comment: See [Permission denied, are you root?](//askubuntu.com/q/223484/301745) on [ubuntu.se] or [What does "are you root?" mean?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/213638/117037) on [unix.se].

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for tips like how to write a good title and starting with your own research.

Comment: Have you actually tried `sudo apt install python3.10`? (BTW the patch version number, 5, probably doesn't matter depending on what you're doing.) Did it give an error that recommended the `sudo apt install software-properties-common -y` command? What was the error that recommended `apt --fix-broken install`? You'll get better answers if you give more details.

Comment: i typed sudo apt install python 3, it tells me python 3 is already the newest version and that i might want to run apt --fix-broken install to correct these but when i type that it returns:E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied) and then asks the same question ;Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root? it also gives same response to sudo apt install software-properties-common -y

Comment: Depends: openjdk-11-jdk-headless (= 11.0.21+9-1~deb11u1) but it is not going to be installed it gives many comments such as this;Depends: python3-dbus but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: python3-software-properties (= 0.96.20.2-2.1) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: do you type ` apt --fix-broken install` only? sudo runs a line as root. so if you don't write `sudo  apt --fix-broken install` it will not run as root.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install **Python 3.10.5** separately from the currently installed **Python 3.9.2**. It requires [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download) or [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation).

Below is the log when installing **Python3.10.5** using pyenv.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is "Python 3.9.2" coming from?

Comment: @wjandrea It is Python installed by default.

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize Chromebook has Linux built-in (Debian Buster). I thought they installed another OS separately.

Comment: how do install it seperately now i have downloaded anaconda